# SQL Server trigger using Inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, inner-join

I am trying to create a trigger that fires only when the inserted last name into the classes table does not match the last names listed in the coaches table.

Here is what I have but it seems to be firing no matter what is inserted into the table.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CoachValidate
ON CLASSES 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF exists (SELECT *
               FROM inserted i
               INNER JOIN COACHES c ON i.lastname <> c.lastname)
        RAISERROR('INVAILD COACH', 10, 0)
        ROLLBACK
END
```

Can someone help me find the error?

Comment: You cannot query the table your trigger is on.

Comment: You do not join the `choaches` table. You join your `classes` table against itself

Comment: @juergend oh crap i went back and fixed that problem but im still getting the same error

Comment: `IF NOT exists (SELECT *
    FROM inserted i
    inner join COACHES c
        ON i.lastname = c.lastname)`

Comment: But actually you should just define a foreign key constraint to the `coaches` table and all that is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method for this.  Instead define the name to be unique on the coaches table (if it is not already) and use a foreign key relationship:

```
alter table coaches add constraint unq_coaches_name unique (lastname);

alter table classes add constraint fk_classes_lastname
    foreign key (lastname) references coaches(lastname);
```

There is no need to replicate in a trigger what the database already does for you.